# How do I do an "if" or "case" statement in VHDL without a process?

Tags: vhdl

So far in my learning of VHDL, I have learned to use an `if` and `case` statement in a process, such as:

```
process(all)
begin
  case Sel is
    when '1' =>      Y <= A ;
    when '0' =>      Y <= B ;
    when others =>   Y <= 'X' ; 
  end case ;
end process ;
```

Is there a way to do this is a more concise fashion, without a process?

Comment: Not having a view inside the designers heads I can't say.  But VHDL is a very formal language: the designers probably wanted any conditional operations to be accompanied by strict and easily-inferred sensitivity lists.

Comment: If and Case statements, like loops, are sequential programming constructs which ought to be familiar from sequential programming languages like Pascal C or Java. So they should be enclosed in a chunk of sequential program ... which is called a process.

Comment: @user_1818839 Could you please explain why they are sequential constructs?

Comment: VHDL's conditional assignment is an "if" statement.    `Y <= A when sel else B ; `

Comment: And there is selected assignment which is equivalent to a concurrent form of case.   Perhaps before bashing you ought to spend more time learning

Comment: "Sequential statements are used to define algorithms for the execution of a subprogram or process; they execute in the order in which they appear." "Concurrent statements are used to define interconnected blocks and processes that jointly describe the overall behavior or structure of a design. Concurrent statements execute asynchronously with respect to each other." "... Additional concurrent statements provide convenient syntax for representing simple, commonly occurring forms of
processes, as well as for representing structural decomposition and regular descriptions." IEEE Std 1076-2008

Comment: This seems, less of an EE question and more of a computer science / language design question.  I would suggest asking there instead.  But keep in mind, the syntax of VHDL, and in turn, Pascal, and ALGOL, were developed so long ago, there are likely very few people around with first-hand experience with those design choices. On a practical side: it just is; learn it, and use it.

Comment: I've re-opened this since it has been edited so that it is no longer opinion-based (the original asked why the language was designed the way it is, which depends on the opinions of the designers -- now it is asking how to perform an operation according to the design of the language).

Answer (score 4):

For using `if` and `case` in a concurrent context, you need to use the assignment form of these called conditional assignment and selected assignment.

The selected assignment that is equivalent to the above case statement is:

```
with Sel select
  Y <= A   when '1',
       B   when '0',
       'X' when others ;
```

If you consider the if statement in a process,

```
process(all)
begin
  if Sel then 
    Y <= A ; 
  else 
    Y <= B ; 
  end if ; 
end process ;
```

The equivalent conditional signal assignment is:

```
Y <= A when Sel else B ;
```

With respect to the language definition, the assignment forms are formally defined as a transformation to the process form - so they work exactly the same way and the assignment form is simply an abbreviation of the process.